# Content beyond the screen is not displayed?

Tags: html, css

I am doing something wrong here but what is it I am not being able to figure out. Is something wrong with my code? Whenever I try to make the screen size smaller the content must be fixed up to a certain width but it's adjusting itself and nothing is displayed beyond it. And here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkwxw9gj/) with the image of what is wrong below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sitefeed">
    <!-- this is the start of site -->
    <header>
        <div class="wrap head-rel">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="logo">
                    <h1>Naveen Niraula</h1>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <article>
            <div class="wrap">
                    <h1>This</h1>

                <p>My dear has kinda some typo somewhere.</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
    <!-- and here is the end -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: consolas;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.sitefeed {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    max-width: 901px;
    min-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
/* ------------- header here ------------------- */
 header ::-moz-selection {
    color: #6cccf2;
}
header ::selection {
    color: #6cccf2;
}
.head-rel {
    position: relative;
}
header {
    background: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}
/* ----------- navigation goes right here ---------------- */
 .nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
.nav li:hover {
    background: #000;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
/* ------------------------ main content goes here ------------------------ */
 #main ::-moz-selection {
    color: #a0249c;
}
#main ::selection {
    color: #a0249c;
}
#main {
    background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

[image: The problem in my HTML]

I want it to display the whole content even when the viewport is small but if the viewport exceeds the webpage I want the background color to measure up to fill that space(left and right). Like the image below . But when I remove the width from `.sitefeed` it's not possible. [image: This is what I want.]

---

Solved.
It seems like `table-layout:fixed;` was causing the problem but now I fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the `overflow:hidden` out of your HTML style.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you don't want the following code:

```
.sitefeed { width: 100% }
```

If you remove this width, you get the background over the whole layout no matter if its outside of the viewport or not. Block elements (display: block) will always take as much width as they can, if not used in conjunction with float. I guess they same is true for display: table. This will take only 100% of the viewport and thus cut the background color at the point where the other content overflows.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkwxw9gj/3/ Do you wanted to achieve this?

*Note: the reason why it overflows from the viewport is your use of min-width: 900px within .wrap-rule. Change that in case you don't want to overflow for reasonable resolutions.*

Comment: Nah mate if I do that the backgound color won't take the whole display.

Comment: Could you please update your question and explain more about what result you want to achieve? I'm confused. If you want to color the space that remains white, why not set a rule on html like html { background-color: #FF0000; } ?

Comment: See that is what I want when viewport is large not just any color I want it to go with what it is !

Answer (score 1):

In this case when you work with the fixed width, just add this with to `header` and `#main`, which are both parents of `.wrap` with fixed width.

```
header, #main {width: 900px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cj9pvz5o/

Comment: but what about the background color ? it's not taking the whole width if i make viewport larger?

Comment: No, background take max 100% of viewport when width isnt defined. You need to change html markup or in this case just set width to parents. Or set min-width.